# Analyzing and Understand what this code does

Tags: c

Long time lurker, first time poster. I'm a student and haven't touched a programming course in two years. Now that I'm taking courses again, I'm having difficulty reading and understanding other people's code. I have a sample-code here from HMC containing a portion of a simple memory allocator in C.

```
void free_block(ptr p) {
     *p = *p & ~1;                         /* clear allocated flag */    
     next = (unsigned*)((char*)p + *p);    /* find next blk */   
     if ((*next & 1) == 0)                 /* if not allocated... */     
     *p += *next;                          /*   add to this block */
      }
```

Despite the comments, I'm still having confusion as to what's going on here exactly. I know what the code does but I would never be able to code this myself. If someone could possibly explain the mathy portions of this code, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: You should include some more code, what is `ptr` for instance?

Comment: This is all the sample code given. PTR would be the pointer passed in.

Comment: My honest advice to you is "put this code aside and come back to it when you understand C much better".  It is doing a whole bunch of things that are ... not *wrong*, but not exactly *normal* either, and explaining them to you at your present stage of understanding is only going to confuse you even more.

Comment: I think the comments are quite good!

Comment: You should ask the authors of this abomin... code directly. Without context, it's hard to tell what they were thinking.

Comment: @Joe The name of the pointer is `p`, the type is `ptr`. Since that is not a standard type, it's not clear what kind of data `p` points at, which makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: IC thanks for the advice, I think I need to as well. My assignment is to construct my own malloc and free functions and this is supposedly the example code I need to do it.

Comment: The old saying "Show me your code and conceal your data structures, and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your data structures, and I won't usually need your code; it'll be obvious." applies quite well here. I can see what the data structure is, but it is tricky enough to deserve a definition with a pretty big comment on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to byte alignment, the last binary bit is not needed for allocation size, 
so instead it is being used as a flag whether that block is allocated.
The size of the allocation, is represented by the value at the beginning of the block.

~1 is a bitwise inverse of 1, meaning instead of 0x01, it is 0xFE

```
 *p = *p & ~1;                         /* clear allocated flag */

 0xFFFFFFFE 
(1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110)
```

A bitwise AND operation with the current value clears the last bit.
The result is the size of the original allocation.

Technically, it dereferences the value at the address at p, and performs a bitwise AND operation with 0xFFFFFFFE effectively keeping all of the value bits but the least significant 
(ensuring the value no longer ends with a 1 if it originally did).

```
 next = (unsigned*)((char*)p + *p);    /* find next blk */
```

'next' is a pointer that point to the subsequent location from 
p + [result value from the above statement]

```
 if ((*next & 1) == 0)                 /* if not allocated... */     
    *p += *next;                          /*   add to this block */
```

if the binary value at 'next' does not end with a one (bitwise AND operation), 
take the value at 'p' and add the value at 'next', and assign the result to the location at 'p'.

So, in other words, if the next block is unallocated, then the original block includes it by adding that block size to itself (effectively removing it's existence).

Good luck.  I hope this helps.

Comment: great!  I modified and formatted it a bit with more info.  let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Joe, The code you posted will work fine to free memory.  You can provide an init function with a parameter of heapsize, allocate a heap of memory upfront, and walk that memory similar to what you posted.  Tracking the allocated blocks (and their corresponding pointers), and maybe in version 2, even defragmenting blocks to make them contiguous.  Actually a good project!  Have fun.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, you really helped me a ton. You're awesome :)

Comment: You are quite welcome Joe.  Don't forget to mark this as answered (checkmark) if it answered.

Answer (score 1):

The operations are presumably clear, so I'll try to handle the actual interpretation in context.

```
*p = *p & ~1;                         /* clear allocated flag */
```

The `~` operator complements the bits.  So, `~1` is all `1` bits except the last, therefore zeroing out the last bit.

We don't know why...yet.

```
next = (unsigned*)((char*)p + *p);    /* find next blk */
```

Here, we have `p` cast to a pointer to a `char` (`(char*)p`), added to whatever the contents of `p` happen to be.  That sum is treated as a pointer to an `unsigned int`.  More or less, you're treating `p` as an offset from itself.

I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea without a *lot* more support code to make sure it's safe, but you're reading the code, not writing it...

```
if ((*next & 1) == 0)                 /* if not allocated... */
```

We now know why the least-significant bit was dropped in the first line.  In this scheme, the code uses that bit to mark that the block has been allocated.

```
    *p += *next;                      /*   add to this block */
```

Here, we're just pushing `p` to beyond the thing we last allocated.

Without knowing what `next` points at, we can guess that it's moving through some sort of linked list-like structure.  It's precarious, though, without knowing how `p` gets populated and how those pointers get structured.

But the upshot is that the code claims the next block and skips the pointer past it.

Comment: Thank's John for your elaborate post.

Comment: I don't know where you got `2 * *p`; I'm not seeing that at all. I see it this way: `p` is a block of memory with the size of the block encoded in an integer stored at the beginning. All sizes in this allocator are even, so the low bit is stolen to represent a free flag. Add the size of the block to the address of the block and you get the address of the next block. When 2 adjacent blocks become free, merge them by adding the sizes and declaring the first block to be that size. There must be a zero-sized block after the last block to prevent a disaster...

Comment: Good catch, @WumpusQ.Wumbley. I overlooked the dereference. That's even more disconcerting, without knowing the support structure. I'll edit.